# Definite integral with exponential and algebraic functions, need an analytical solution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Can anybody help me with this integral? I need an analytical solution for this, and maybe $\textit{Mathematica}$ can help too:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{x=\sqrt{\alpha}}^{\infty} e^{-(ax^2+\frac{b}{x^2})}   ~\sqrt{\frac{x^4+cx^2+d}{x^4-\alpha x^2}}  ~~dx. 
\end{equation}

where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $\alpha$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: Can you please provide details on what you have tried, as well as a context of this problem.

Comment: I am trying to derive Weiss-Weinstein Bound for a distributed estimation problem, the initial integral looks very complicated, I have tried to simplify the integral and couple of change of variables and re-writing the integral. The parameters a, b, c, d are functions of my unknown variances, noise variances and .. . @JonathanDavidson

Comment: Just to clarify, $e$ is __not__ Euler's constant? Because $e^\cdots$ is almost universally understood to be that, making your choice of $e$ quite unfortunate.

Comment: @orlp No it is not :) .

Comment: Perhaps one of these more exotic substituions might work?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: So when you write $e^{-(ax^2 + bx^{-2})}$, the $e$ here is the same constant as the one that appears in the limits of integration and the denominator of the radical, not the constant $\approx 2.718$? Because if so you really need to use a different letter.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson I'll try again, however I have tried all of Euler's substitutions in 'Gradshteyn, Ryzhik, Tables of integrals'

Comment: Surely your $e$ in $e^{...}$ is the base of the natural logarithms.  No?!

Comment: @eyeballfrog I edited the post, $e$ is like 'exp{}' so , yes e\approx 2.71..

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that's is right.

Comment: I am gonna try some contour integration methods

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Thank you

Comment: Though it's by no means a full solution, I would suggest the substitution $x^2\rightarrow u$ to simplify the integrand.

Comment: @eyeballfrog correct , it will simplify a little bit.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson for a special case of my problem it can be written as following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363212/definite-integral-need-analytical-solution